# Rerunning PHP script without javascript

Tags: php, cron

I am making a script that scrapes certain data from a website, and may iterate over multiple pages on the site if certain conditions exist, a new page iteration requires a script reload since the function I am using in PHP to get the page I'm scraping can only be called once, when I was running the script in a browser I got around this by simply reloading with javascript. However, now I am trying to set this task with a cronjob and so the javascript won't work...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) is what are you looking for.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

If you're running php from CLI/cron you can build one more process that would use [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) and open child processes one after another.

Comment: I am running a php script with a cronjob, not a browser

Answer (score 0):

The only way to rerun a PHP script is to call it again since the server needs to run the script. if you can't use Javascript and you can't use the suggestion Vyktor offered then you just can't.

Basically the only thing JS and  does is call the server to execute the script and return the results to you, just as if you are pressing F5 or hitting the refresh button.
if you can emulate this in another way, then perhaps you can work around it. but I don't think its practical.